# home.php show blog posts as grid view

Tags: php, theme-development, loop, themes

I am currently working on my `home.php` file for my theme, and I'm planning on displaying my the last Blog posts in a "grid view", so that there are 4 containers in a row, containing the title and some more information.

I tried out some things, but nothing worked the way I wanted it to. The last thing I did was putting a for loop like this:

```
<?php
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 6; $x++) :
?>
        <div id="home_post_<?php echo $x ?> " class="home_post">
            <?php
                if(have_posts()) :
                    while(have_posts()) : the_post();
                        get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'home');
                    endwhile;
                endif;
            ?>
        </div>
<?php
    endfor;
?>
```

Around my loop, but that way, every new `div` is filled with the first overall Blogpost, so this is not the way to do it.

Is there a clever way to work with a loop that "generates" divs or am I just on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit hard to guess, what exactly do you want to achieve (you've mentioned something about four posts in a row and then there is number 6 in your for loop), but...

If you want to display only 4 posts in your loop, then you can use `current_post` field of `$wp_query`, so the loop may look like this:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() and $wp_query->current_post < 4) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="home_post_<?php echo $wp_query->current_post ?>">
        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'home'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
// you don't do anything if there are no posts, so there's no point in checking if (have_posts())
```

Another thing worth to remember is that if you'd like to show only 4 posts on your home, then it's a good idea to modify query accordingly - so it doesn't get redundant posts.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself, here is how i did it:

```
       <?php

            $x = 0;
        if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts() and $x <=5) : the_post(); ?>
            <div id="home_post_<?php echo $x ?>"> <?php
            get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'home');
                ?> </div> <?php
            $x++;
        endwhile;
        endif;
        ?>
```

Comment: You don't need to use your custom counter (`$x`). Take a look at my answer.